# Linking issues with make to library in separate folder

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

So I'm trying to run make on a program that has object files and libraries included elsewhere. However, when I try and link these object files and a library, I get a bunch of errors with linking saying the functions have an undefined reference.

```
$(OBJ)/monitor.o: monitor.c list.h $(PTDIR)/standards.h $(PTDIR)/os.h $(OBJ)
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) -c monitor.c -I. -o $@

$(OBJ)/reader-writer.o: reader-writer.h reader-writer.c $(PTDIR)/os.h $(PTDIR)/standards.h $(OBJ)
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) -c reader-writer.c -I. -o $@

$(OBJ)/reader-writer-monitor.o: reader-writer-monitor.c $(PTDIR)/os.h $(PTDIR)/standards.h $(OBJ)
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) -c reader-writer-monitor.c -I. -o $@

$(OBJ)/libMonitor.a: $(OBJ)/monitor.o $(OBJ)/list_adders.o $(OBJ)/list_removers.o    $(OBJ)/list_movers.o
    ar -crvs $@ $^

$(OBJ)/reader-writer-test.o: reader-writer-test.c
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) -c $^ -I. -o $@

$(OBJ)/reader-writer-test: $(OBJ)/reader-writer-test.o (OBJ)/reader-writer.o $(OBJ)/libMonitor.a $(PTDIR)/os.h $(PTDIR)/standards.h
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) $^ -o reader-writer-test

 $(OBJ)/reader-writer-monitor:  $(OBJ)/reader-writer-monitor.o $(OBJ)/reader-writer.o     $(OBJ)/libMonitor.a  $(PTDIR)/os.h $(PTDIR)/standards.h
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) $(OBJ)/reader-writer-monitor.o $(OBJ)/reader-writer.o -L./$(OBJ)/Monitor  -o     reader-writer-monitor
```

It's to do both with reader-writer and reader-writer-monitor. I know it's a linking issue but I can't seem to find where it is pointed out. I think it has to do with the .o declaration of everything, as the errors do pertain to a few other undefined references to pthreads. Any help on how to fix this?

```
user@tux2:~/Desktop/CMPT332/group18/Trunk/A2> make all
gcc -Wall -g -pedantic -c list_adders.c -I. -o objdir/Linux/list_addersB.o -m64
list_adders.c: In function 'ListCreate':
list.h:91:4: warning: return makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
    return NULL;\
    ^
list_adders.c:85:4: note: in expansion of macro 'HeaderGet'
    HeaderGet(headerRet);
    ^
gcc -Wall -g -pedantic -c list_movers.c -I. -o objdir/Linux/list_moversB.o -m64
gcc -Wall -g -pedantic -c list_removers.c -I. -o objdir/Linux/list_removersB.o -m64
ar -rcs objdir/Linux/libListB.a objdir/Linux/list_addersB.o objdir/Linux/list_moversB.o objdir/Linux/list_removersB.o
gcc -Wall -g -pedantic -c list_adders.c -I. -o objdir/Linux/list_adders.o -m32
gcc -Wall -g -pedantic -c list_movers.c -I. -o objdir/Linux/list_movers.o -m32
gcc -Wall -g -pedantic -c list_removers.c -I. -o objdir/Linux/list_removers.o -m32
ar -rcs objdir/Linux/libListC.a objdir/Linux/list_adders.o objdir/Linux/list_movers.o objdir/Linux/list_removers.o
gcc -Wall -g -pedantic -c monitor.c -I. -o objdir/Linux/monitor.o
ar -rcs objdir/Linux/libMonitor.a objdir/Linux/monitor.o objdir/Linux/list_adders.o objdir/Linux/list_removers.o objdir/Linux/list_movers.o
gcc -Wall -g -pedantic -c reader-writer-monitor.c -I. -o objdir/Linux/reader-writer-monitor.o
gcc -Wall -g -pedantic -c reader-writer.c -I. -o objdir/Linux/reader-writer.o
gcc -Wall -g -pedantic objdir/Linux/reader-writer-monitor.o objdir/Linux/reader-writer.o -L./objdir/Linux/Monitor  -o reader-writer-monitor
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-mageia-linux-gnu/4.8.2/../../../../lib64/crt1.o: In function '_start':
/home/iurt/rpmbuild/BUILD/glibc-2.18/csu/../sysdeps/x86_64/start.S:118: undefined reference to 'main'
objdir/Linux/reader-writer-monitor.o: In function 'StartRead':
/student/user/Desktop/CMPT332/group18/Trunk/A2/reader-writer-monitor.c:36: undefined reference to 'MonEnter'
/student/user/Desktop/CMPT332/group18/Trunk/A2/reader-writer-monitor.c:41: undefined reference to 'MonWait'
/student/user/Desktop/CMPT332/group18/Trunk/A2/reader-writer-monitor.c:54: undefined reference to 'MonSignal'
/student/user/Desktop/CMPT332/group18/Trunk/A2/reader-writer-monitor.c:56: undefined reference to 'MonLeave'
objdir/Linux/reader-writer-monitor.o: In function 'StopRead':
/student/user/Desktop/CMPT332/group18/Trunk/A2/reader-writer-monitor.c:62: undefined reference to 'MonEnter'
/student/user/Desktop/CMPT332/group18/Trunk/A2/reader-writer-monitor.c:66: undefined reference to 'MonSignal'
/student/user/Desktop/CMPT332/group18/Trunk/A2/reader-writer-monitor.c:67: undefined reference to 'MonLeave'
objdir/Linux/reader-writer-monitor.o: In function 'StartWrite':
/student/user/Desktop/CMPT332/group18/Trunk/A2/reader-writer-monitor.c:74: undefined reference to 'MonEnter'
/student/user/Desktop/CMPT332/group18/Trunk/A2/reader-writer-monitor.c:78: undefined reference to 'MonWait'
/student/user/Desktop/CMPT332/group18/Trunk/A2/reader-writer-monitor.c:80: undefined reference to 'MonLeave'
objdir/Linux/reader-writer-monitor.o: In function 'StopWrite':
/student/user/Desktop/CMPT332/group18/Trunk/A2/reader-writer-monitor.c:85: undefined reference to 'MonEnter'
/student/user/Desktop/CMPT332/group18/Trunk/A2/reader-writer-monitor.c:89: undefined reference to 'MyPid'
/student/user/Desktop/CMPT332/group18/Trunk/A2/reader-writer-monitor.c:96: undefined reference to 'MonSignal'
/student/user/Desktop/CMPT332/group18/Trunk/A2/reader-writer-monitor.c:98: undefined reference to 'MonLeave'
objdir/Linux/reader-writer.o: In function 'reader':
/student/user/Desktop/CMPT332/group18/Trunk/A2/reader-writer.c:39: undefined reference to 'Sleep'
/student/user/Desktop/CMPT332/group18/Trunk/A2/reader-writer.c:42: undefined reference to 'Sleep'
objdir/Linux/reader-writer.o: In function 'writer':
/student/user/Desktop/CMPT332/group18/Trunk/A2/reader-writer.c:59: undefined reference to 'Sleep'
/student/user/Desktop/CMPT332/group18/Trunk/A2/reader-writer.c:62: undefined reference to 'Sleep'
objdir/Linux/reader-writer.o: In function 'mainp':
/student/user/Desktop/CMPT332/group18/Trunk/A2/reader-writer.c:73: undefined reference to 'MonInit'
/student/user/Desktop/CMPT332/group18/Trunk/A2/reader-writer.c:77: undefined reference to 'Create'
/student/user/Desktop/CMPT332/group18/Trunk/A2/reader-writer.c:79: undefined reference to 'Create'
/student/user/Desktop/CMPT332/group18/Trunk/A2/reader-writer.c:81: undefined reference to 'Create'
/student/user/Desktop/CMPT332/group18/Trunk/A2/reader-writer.c:83: undefined reference to 'Create'
/student/user/Desktop/CMPT332/group18/Trunk/A2/reader-writer.c:85: undefined reference to 'Create'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Including the errors and the actual make output is going to be useful.

Comment: Will do as soon as I get back to my PC!

Comment: Where are those symbols (`MonEnter`, `MonWait`, `MonSignal`, etc.) defined?

Comment: They are defined within Monitor.h and are coded within the monitor library (which is monitor.o, and the list commands).

Comment: `monitor.o` or `reader-writer-monitor.o` because only `reader-writer-monitor.o` is being linked into `reader-writer-monitor` `monitor.o` is not on that linking line. And neither is `libMonitor.a` (presumably intended to be used through `-lMonitor`).

Comment: So, what you're saying is I should add `$(OBJ)/monitor.o` to my `reader-writer-monitor` lines? And yes, `libMonitor.a` is linked by the `-L./$(OBJ)/Monitor`, should it be done by `-l$(OBJ)Monitor`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63899/discussion-between-phlex-and-etan-reisner).